# Regex creates incredibly heavy load

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex that creates an incredibly high load in both Java and online websites that help you test regexes. The regex is:

```
import (\s*\w*\.*)*;
```

Which runs smoothly for

```
import bla.foo.bloo.blaf.blooo;
```

but seems to completely break down (just keeps processing infinitely) for

```
import static bla.foo.bloo.somestatic.blaaaaaat.blooo.foo.*;
```

I am wondering why this is happening, a fix to pick up both is using

```
import (\s*\w*\.*\**)*;
```

but I don't see what creates the incredibly heavy load.

Comment: I'm tempted to put this as an answer and suffer the downvotes, but, when push comes to shove, regular expression parsers are slow. That's life. If there's another way for your requirements, then adopt it.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why the first regex seems to run forever for the second sample.

Comment: It's taking ages because the number of possible matches grows exponentially with the length of the string you're attempting to match.

Comment: squeamish and nemetroid answered you're question correctly.  You should spend some time crafting that regex to be a little less ambiguous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what's making it slow is the fact that you have stars both inside the parentheses and outside them. If you have a regex like `(\w*)*` and try to match "foo", you can do so in a number of ways:

```
(foo)
(fo)(o)
(f)(oo)
(f)(o)(o)
```

(the parentheses here are to be understood as `(\w*)` matching once).

Since regexes go depth-first this isn't an issue when you actually get a match, but for a string that doesn't match it has to go through *all* the variations like the above before it may conclude that there is no match.

For a long string that's a very large number of variations. Each new character may either continue the current `(\w*\s*\.*)` or start a new one, giving a complexity of O(2^n).

Try this one for a faster result: `import [\w\s\.]*;`.